# FFmpeg: How to get frames decreasing in size

Tags: ffmpeg

I encode frames using the following encoder configuration:

```
codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoderH264);
codecContext->width = width;
codecContext->height = height;
codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
codecContext->time_base.num = 1;
codecContext->time_base.den = 1;
codecContext->has_b_frames = false;
av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);
av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "crf", "30", 0);
```

It creates a proper encoder that works. What bugs me though is that consecutive frames are not always decreasing in size. I would hope to have an FFmpeg encoder that in the first frame produces an image of, say, 0.5 mb, then 0.05 mb, then frames having 0.01 mb. My NVIDIA hardware encoder does just that. But the above FFmpeg config gives me such frames at the beginning:

1556

200

225

238

238

238

238

828745

216

352

714

1129

Sizes vary a bit later on until all settles at 242 bytes.
Is there a way to make the encoder be something like:

100000

20000

1000

50

50

50

...

?

Answer (score 0):

Frame size is largely determined by frame type and frame complexity. I frames for example will almost always be larger than B/P frames that follow because I frames encode a full picture while other frames only encoded changes in that picture. Most codecs insert I frames periodically so you can seek within the file without needing to download and/or decode the entire thing. Secondly, there is a concept of information density (read about information theory) that states data and information are not the same. For example the data “aaaaaaaaaa” contains “ax10”. I can write it more compact. but “hebphwhcqo” is difficult to represent shorter. Hence a frame that has little information (all black) will be smaller that a frame with lots of information, like a picture of fireworks.

And to answer your question: What your asking for isn’t a thing. If you’re encoding a non moving image, it MAY work out that way if you disable scene change detection and periodic I frames.

Comment: Can't I somehow enforce the first frame to be intra frame? Cause right now it looks like I need to encode and subsequently decode quite a few frames before I have any actual image data.

Comment: The first frame is always an Intra frame.

Comment: The first packet I extract from codec's context has ~1500 bytes

Comment: Doesn’t matter. Use something like ffprobe -show_frames to see the type.

Comment: It is indeed an intra frame. But that one frame is not enough for the decoder to decode an entire image. I get blank greenish screen after decoding that first frame. I would expect every intra frame to be "self-contained".
I don't know how but there must be a way to config FFmpeg the same way I do config NVIDIA hardware encoder. In such a way that the first frame is intra and is "self-decodable", whereas the following are always decreasing in size and are predicted frames